# visual c# internationalization

Tags: c#, internationalization

the example given here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa330254%28VS.71%29.aspx) from MSDN about internationalization does not work for me. I've used this snippet

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Resources.Form1", this.GetType().Assembly);
this.Text = rm.GetString("this.Text");
```

but throws me the following exception related to first line:
System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException
I need to know why the first parameter of ResourceManager constructor is not good. I've tried also with "Form1". The resource file name is Form1.it-IT.resx or Form1.en-GB.resx and so on.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a string from your resources, you can do as follows:

- as described in this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xhwfctz(v=vs.80).aspx) **Add** the string to resources:

> 1. With a project selected in Solution Explorer, on the Project menu,
>      click Properties.
> 2. Click the Resources tab. On the Resource Designer
>      toolbar, point to the resource view drop-down, click the arrow, and
>      make sure it is set to Strings (which is the default). A settings grid
>      will appear, displaying the strings maintained by that instance of the
>      Resource Designer.
> 3. Click on the Name column of the last row in the
>      grid, which is marked with an asterisk (*).
> 4. In the Name column, enter a name for the string.
> 5. In the Value column, enter the string to be used as a resource.

- In run time **get** the resource:

  `this.Text = MyNamspace.Properties.Resources.StringResourcesName;`

Another way would be to follow the instructions in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270079/how-can-i-access-embedded-resources-in-a-c-sharp-project)

Answer (score 1):

You need a default resource file, rename Form1.en-GB.resx to Form1.resx This will be the default, and if cultureinfo is IT, the resource manager will first look in the Form1.it-IT.resx file, afterwards in the Form1.resx file if key was not found in it-IT version.

Comment: I have the Form1.resx file together with other resx files, but the error persists. I've created that files directly in Visual Studio, changing language parameter in form properties.